# Mocking Static classes using Typemock

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-2.5, typemock, typemock-isolator

I am having a class as follows. I would like to know how can we mock this class using Typemock

```
public static class MyClass
{
   public static string MyFunction()
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no special syntax required for static method mocking. You should be able to use the AAA syntax as usual.

```
Isolate.Fake.WhenCalled(() => MyClass.MyFunction()).WillReturn("mock");
```

There is some [great documentation about this on the Typemock site](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##Ref.chm/Documentation/StaticAAA.html).

Comment: But the problem is we can't create an object reference for this class since it is static

Comment: You don't need to create an instance. Just start out with the WhenCalled statement. The example I wrote up there doesn't create any instance - you could actually use that given your example class from your question. Check out that documentation, it shows more examples.

Comment: some how i managed to solve this. thanks for the reference :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please post how you actually did answer the question so future readers can benefit. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the answer to this?  My static method keeps calling the original method even though I specify a fake.